# Replace (translate) one char to many

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a string. In this string i need replace all special characters (0-31 codes) with chosen representation. Representations may be of different formats. May be \x??, or \0???, or 10,13 -> \n, 9 -> \t and all others characters are converting to null. Summary - i need find all symbols with 0-31 codes and replace all of them for appropriate representation, which can be zero or more symbols.

Solution should work in 9.2 Oracle (thats mean no regexp) and shuld be very fast.

I know that TRANSLATE function is really fast. Buth there i can`t replace one symbol for many. I can replace only one by one.

My barbarian (and easy) solution is to create lists with 32 elements for each representation. Than for chosen representation make a loop over the list. Inside the loop call REPLACE function. In this case i would always call replace 32-times. I think that is expencive.

Are you have any idea?

Comment: Please post your "barbarian solution" - it sounds like the way to go in this scenario. Then we can point out if it can be made more efficient. In the end I suspect a whole bunch of calls to REPLACE will be required, but may be less expensive than you think.

Comment: ok )) i try many ways and found that lot of nested REPLACE is the most efficient way.

Predefined lists with 32 elements working at least two times slower.

Plus, ACE of Oracle Forum says that he successfully use nested replaces in many projects.

see my solution below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's my "barbarian", but effective solution. it's main part:

```
res :=
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                            REPLACE(
                                REPLACE(
                                    REPLACE(
                                        REPLACE(
                                            REPLACE(
                                                REPLACE(
                                                    REPLACE(
                                                        REPLACE(
                                                            REPLACE(
                                                                REPLACE(
                                                                    REPLACE(
                                                                        REPLACE(
                                                                            REPLACE(
                                                                                REPLACE(
                                                                                    REPLACE(
                                                                                        REPLACE(
                                                                                            REPLACE(
                                                                                                REPLACE(
                                                                                                    REPLACE(
                                                                                                        REPLACE(
                                                                                                            REPLACE(
                                                                                                                REPLACE(
                                                                                                                    REPLACE(
                                                                                                                        REPLACE(
                                                                                                                            REPLACE(
                                                                                                                                REPLACE(
                                                                                                                                    p_txt,
                                                                                                                                    CHR(0),
                                                                                                                                    '\0x00'
                                                                                                                                ),
                                                                                                                                CHR(1),
                                                                                                                                '\0x01'
                                                                                                                            ),
                                                                                                                            CHR(2),
                                                                                                                            '\0x02'
                                                                                                                        ),
                                                                                                                        CHR(3),
                                                                                                                        '\0x03'
                                                                                                                    ),
                                                                                                                    CHR(4),
                                                                                                                    '\0x04'
                                                                                                                ),
                                                                                                                CHR(5),
                                                                                                                '\0x05'
                                                                                                            ),
                                                                                                            CHR(6),
                                                                                                            '\0x06'
                                                                                                        ),
                                                                                                        CHR(7),
                                                                                                        '\0x07'
                                                                                                    ),
                                                                                                    CHR(8),
                                                                                                    '\0x08'
                                                                                                ),
                                                                                                CHR(9),
                                                                                                '\0x09'
                                                                                            ),
                                                                                            CHR(10),
                                                                                            '\0x0A'
                                                                                        ),
                                                                                        CHR(11),
                                                                                        '\0x0B'
                                                                                    ),
                                                                                    CHR(12),
                                                                                    '\0x0C'
                                                                                ),
                                                                                CHR(13),
                                                                                '\0x0D'
                                                                            ),
                                                                            CHR(14),
                                                                            '\0x0E'
                                                                        ),
                                                                        CHR(15),
                                                                        '\0x0F'
                                                                    ),
                                                                    CHR(16),
                                                                    '\0x10'
                                                                ),
                                                                CHR(17),
                                                                '\0x11'
                                                            ),
                                                            CHR(18),
                                                            '\0x12'
                                                        ),
                                                        CHR(19),
                                                        '\0x13'
                                                    ),
                                                    CHR(20),
                                                    '\0x14'
                                                ),
                                                CHR(21),
                                                '\0x15'
                                            ),
                                            CHR(22),
                                            '\0x16'
                                        ),
                                        CHR(23),
                                        '\0x17'
                                    ),
                                    CHR(24),
                                    '\0x18'
                                ),
                                CHR(25),
                                '\0x19'
                            ),
                            CHR(26),
                            '\0x1A'
                        ),
                        CHR(27),
                        '\0x1B'
                    ),
                    CHR(28),
                    '\0x1C'
                ),
                CHR(29),
                '\0x1D'
            ),
            CHR(30),
            '\0x1E'
        ),
        CHR(31),
        '\0x1F'
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use decode. Documentation can be found here:

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php

If you're using it in a pl/sql procedure or function you could use it like this:

```
SELECT decode(your_string, 'var1', 'repl1', 'var2', 'repl2', 'varN', 'replN')
INTO l_decoded_string
FROM dual;
```

Comment: my english is not good :( input string may be any lenght and may conain any characters. not only with 0-31 codes. i should don`t touch characters with codes > 31, but characters with codes <= 31 i should replace with chosen representation. decode is usefull for character with a short list of replacement variants. if we have  32 possible replacements, than decode statement will be awfully big and unreadable.

Comment: OK, du you have a table containing all the codes that should be replaced, and what they should be replaced with?

Comment: I think about feasibility of that table. if you use table, it could not be applied DETERMINISTIC hint :(

Comment: Does it really matter if the DECODE is big?  You will only write it once, and it well never in all likelihood need maintenance.  Suppose Oracle's own ASCII function implementation involved a huge 255 element DECODE (I'm not suggesting it does, just suppose!) - who actually cares?

Comment: the problem is to replace one char with many chars. replacement may be null or variable length. input string may be variable length and there is may may be 0 or variable count of characters needs to be replaced. i have an idea to use DECODE + SUBSTR + CONNECT BY over the input string and then transpose resulting table and concatenate columns. but it is difficult.

now i`m testing solution with 32-deep replacement. its quite readable then sql with decode :) later i post solution here.

Answer (score 1):

This would probably perform just as well, and be easier to read and maintain:

```
function trans (p_in in varchar2) return varchar2 is
   l_out varchar2(32767) := p_in;
begin
   if length(l_out) > 0 then
      for i in 0..31 loop
         l_out := REPLACE(l_out, CHR(i), '\0x' || to_char(i,'FM0X'));
      end loop;
   end if;
   return l_out;
end trans;
```